# Someone please tell me why my code gives me wrong answers.The program is supposed to accept an integer input and give the corresponding factorial.I

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial_calculator(int n);

void main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter a number to get its factorial: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n",n,factorial_calculator(n));
}//end main

int factorial_calculator(int n)
{
    int factorial;
    int number;

    for(number=1;number<=n;number++)
    {
        factorial=factorial*number;
        return factorial;
    }
}//end factorial_Calculator
```

Comment: This variable int factorial; is not initialized.

Comment: You're returning factorial within the for loop. So it's not iterating

Comment: Please format your code properly with indentation and without the excessive blank lines.  It's almost unreadable as is.

Answer (score 1):

You should not `return` in the body of the loop:

```
for(number=1;number<=n;number++)
{
    factorial=factorial*number;
    return factorial;
}
```

should be

```
for(number=1;number<=n;number++)
{
    factorial=factorial*number;
}
return factorial;
```

otherwise you return the value in the first iteration of the `for` loop.

also, as pointed out by @spartygw in comments, you need to initialize `factorial`:

```
int factorial = 1;
```

and use the proper signature for `main`: `int main(void)` instead of `void main()`

Also, since `scanf` can fail, initialize `n`

```
int n = 0;
```

and pass the absolute value of `n` in order to avoid an infinite loop if a negative number is entered:

```
printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n",n,factorial_calculator(abs(n)));
```

Comment: He's also not initializing factorial. Add that to your sample